# Pending transactions Geth private Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, geth-debugging, microsoft-azure

I have an ethereum consortium blockchain based on Azure (Geth 1.7.3). I've been experimenting with an application which has a very simple smart contract. 
The contracts itself, stores data that comes from the Javascript console (it's basically a mapping that maps to a structure of several strings).

I launch the **ContractInstance.function.sendTransaction (x,y,z, {from: eth.accounts[0], gas:2000000, gasPrice: web3.toWei(1140, "gwei")});)** but when I check the txpool I see some other transactions there that are not associated with these contracts. These ones are not red marked.

Does anyone else knows why this happens? I can only fix the problem cleaning the **transactions.rlp** file and launch the transactions again. But after some transactions I get the same problem.

[image]

Is this related to Geth version? I increased the gas Price tremendously but even with this stay the same problem.

Hope someone can help. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Geth is being used to run your node and stores all incoming transactions, maybe you have another account which uses geth and all transactions emanating from them will be listed in the txpool.

Get the nonce of last transaction confirmed and redo the transaction which has the next nonce. This might fix the issue